# How to refer to the pointer to the current element of the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

There is a code that displays a list of posts:

```
import React from "react";


type respX = {
    "id": any,
    "userId": any,
    "title": any,
    "body": any,
}

interface PropsI {
}

interface StateI {
    data: respX [];
}

export class ComponentPostList extends React.Component <PropsI, StateI> {

    state: StateI = {data: []}

    async componentDidMount () {
        const response = await fetch (`https: // jsonplaceholder.typicode.com / posts /`);
        const json = await response.json ();
        this.setState ({data: json});
    }


    render () {
        return (
            <div className = "About">
                {this.state.data.map (el => (
                    <li key = {el.id}>
                        {el.title}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to click on each post (click on `<li>`) to make a request for a separate post, for example https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1, where `1` is the post number.

Comment: `onClick={e => this.loadPost(el.id)}` use this and create a method.

Comment: @Jai Thank you! What the loadPost method should look like? Like componentDidMount()?

Comment: That is a method which will make a call for the specific posts as you mentioned.

Comment: @Jai  how can I correctly use concat to join https: // jsonplaceholder.typicode.com / posts / + 'el.id' in this method?

Comment: just added an answer. you can follow that.

Comment: In your loadPost method, just: const concat = `${path}${id}` (template string, as stackoverflow parse it as a code sample), with path referring to your path above and id to the parameter el.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the click event on the element itself:

```
<li key = {el.id} onClick={e => this.loadPost(el.id)}>
```

Now you can have this method in your component:

```
async loadPost(id){
    // pass the id in the template string variable
    const response = await fetch (`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState ({post: json}); // <--------have a post
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass post id on click on li, like this:

```
{this.state.data.map (el => (
    <li key = {el.id} onClick={() => this.onPostClick(el.id)}>
        {el.title}
    </li>
 ))}
```

and add function:

```
onPostClick = async (id: string) => {}
```

Or another way:

```
{this.state.data.map (el => (
     <li key = {el.id} onClick={this.onPostClick(el.id)}>
         {el.title}
     </li>
))}

onPostClick = (id: string) => async () => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked 2 questions, actually. The short answer to "How to refer to the pointer to the current element of the array?" is:

`this.state.data.map((el, index) => { })`
The 2nd parameter returned in an array.map() method is the index.

To answer your other question, how to handle getting another post on click:

Define an async method to get post (I recommend using fetch), and add it to the onClick handler when you click the li, and pass the id to it.

```
import React from "react";


type respX = {
    "id": any,
    "userId": any,
    "title": any,
    "body": any,
}

interface PropsI {
}

interface StateI {
    data: respX [];
}

export class ComponentPostList extends React.Component <PropsI, StateI> {

    state: StateI = {data: []}

    async componentDidMount () {
        const response = await fetch (`https: // jsonplaceholder.typicode.com / posts /`);
        const json = await response.json ();
        this.setState ({data: json});
    }

    async getPost(id) => { /*fetch post using id*/ }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className = "About">
                {this.state.data.map (el => (
                    <li key={el.id} onClick={() => this.getPost(el.id)}>
                        {el.title}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```